# How do I use shout power levels?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have all three words in a shout, but I can't see any difference in the shout compared to when I just had one word, and the recharge time for the power is still on the lower level.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to hold the <kbd>Z</kbd> (PC), <kbd>R2</kbd> (PS3), or <kbd>RB</kbd> (Xbox 360) key for a while to charge the shout and use more words.

Answer (score 6):

The longer you hold the "Shout-Key", the more words of the Shout will be used. As seen in [this wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_shouts), the cooldown is differs. For example the first shout you learn. If you use it just for a moment, you only shout the first word. Cooldown for this is 15 seconds. If you hold it longer you use two words (cooldown 20 seconds). Holding the button even a few moments more, will let you shout all the three words, wich will also set the cooldown to 45 seconds.