# Am I using Shouts Correctly?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use shout power levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36764/how-do-i-use-shout-power-levels)

I have all three words of Unrelenting Force, but when I hit my shout button it seems only one word is coming out of my mouth.  Am I using the full effect of the shout or is there a key combination to use a more powerful Unrelenting Force?

Comment: Sorry I did a search for Using Shout, Multiple Shout Words, even when I was typing out the question that dupe did not come up in the list on the right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The longer you hold down the shout button/key, the more force behind your shouts.  If you hold down the button when unrelenting force is selected, you should hear Dovahkiin shoult all three words (fus ro dah)

Comment: mine is only fus dah, i know i've learned all 3 because i remember doing it, also in the menu it shows all 3 (including roh). Anyone know why this could be and how to fix it?